# Change column names for multiple data frames in a loop

Tags: r

I have four data frames for four different river data sets (the rivers are Main, Danube, Isar and Inn). The data frames are all of the same dimensions and are named as follows: "df_Main", "df_Danube", "df_Isar" and "df_Inn".
In order for handy plotting afterwards, I need all the data frames to have the same column names.
I thought it can easily be achieved by this:

```
rivers <- c("Main", "Danube", "Isar", "Inn")
for (i in 1:length(rivers)) {
  colnames(get(paste0("df_", rivers[i]))) <- c("bla", "bla", "bla", "bla")
}
```

But that does not work.
Anybody with an idea?

Comment: Though I am not clear on your query, but I think you require `setNames`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you give an example how that should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go this way you probably need the function `assign`. As an example:

```
rivers <- c("df_Main", "df_Danube", "df_Isar", "df_Inn")

for (i in rivers) {
  x=get(i)
  colnames(x) <- c("bla", "bla", "bla", "bla")
  assign(i,x)
}
```

If you need to do it for more than 4 data.frames maybe you should check an apply function.

Still, if you plan to plot it via ggplot2 it might be more useful to have it in a single df.

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo code

```
library(purrr) # using purrr for map function
# create a list of 4 data frame
# another alternatives is define the initial list with names
list_4_river_df <- list(df_Main = df_Main, df_Danube = df_Danube,
                        df_Isar = df_Isar, df_Inn = df_Inn)
# map setNames to each dataframe in the list
list_4_river_df <- map(list_4_river_df, setNames, nm = c("bla_1", "bla_2", "bla_3", "bla_4", "bla_5"))

# then list2env should work perfectly
list2env(list_4_river_df,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks this basically works in the created list. But when I try to retrieve the data frames from the list by ```list2env(list_4_river_df,envir = .GlobalEnv)``` I receive the following error: ```names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x```.

Comment: Just update the answer to include the `list2env` usecase

Comment: Well the command ```list2env``` does not create an error message anymore, but when I look at the single data frames afterwards they still have the old column names. :(

Comment: Hi there the code I share with you just show the result - you need to put them together to make it work. - I adjust the answers though

Comment: great, now it did the job perfectly. Thanks!